# Corda: ContractCode for the final transaction having multiple input states getting consumed and one output cash state remaining

Tags: corda

I am trying to figure out what the contract code for a cash transfer transaction would look like in a scenario where this transaction will result in evolving the input cash state to an output cash state, while consuming all the states of previous transactions. For example, there are multiple  agreements between two parties which hold true until the payment is done. Once the cash transfer has taken place, those agreements need to be consumed so that they are not used in further transactions. So logically, how will the contract code, including the commands, look like?

Answer (score 0):

You would build a transaction with all the existing cash states as inputs, and create new, corresponding cash states as the outputs.

You'd include some kind of `move` or `transfer` command.

The contract might impose the following constraints:

- Total value of inputs == total value of outputs
- Same currency for all input and output states
- Move command is present
- Move command has signature from all the current owners of the cash

Comment: Thanks @joel! But I was looking for the contract code of a transaction which had one I/O cash state and other I/O states were bilateral agreements that I needed to close once payment was done. The agreements are between two parties and the payment is being done by their respective banks; so essentially, the transaction requires signatures from 4 parties - the two agreement making parties and their two banks. Is this possible? What should be the constraints in this case? Hope am making sense.

Comment: That's fine - a transaction can have many required signers, and many kinds of input and output states. In your case, the contracts for the bilateral agreement might specify that: [1]. There are four required signers (the agreers and the banks); [2]. The input bilateral agreements have an "open" flag, while the output bilateral agreements have a "closed" flag; [3]. The value of the I/O cash matches the total value of the bilateral agreements being closed. Then the transaction would need to satisfy both the original cash contract and the bilateral agreement contract.

Comment: Thanks @joel. This helps!